# DateTime gets changed to Date in service reference proxy

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, datetime, .net-4.0

When I add a service reference to my VB.Net project all of the properties of type DateTime get changed to type Date. The project is ASP.Net using framework 4.0.  The web service being referenced is C# framework 4.0.

How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "VB.Net 4.0 " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `Date` in VB is just an alias for the `DateTime` CLR type. For example, this code:

```
Public Class Foo

  Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
      Dim x As Date = New Date
  End Sub

End Class
```

compiles to the equivalent of:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime x = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

So the types aren't really being changed - they're just being shown as `Date`. It's much like the difference between `Int32` and `int` in C#, I believe. (There may be some other differences such as extra methods provided via `Date`, but the values are of the same type.)